# How often do the special characters appear?

Tags: fingered

In the game Fingered, special characters can appear occasionally among the regular characters that can unlock an achievement if they have been executed (even if it's the wrong person, which most of the time seems to be the case). [There's even a Steam guide outlining each of the characters.](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=502277564)

But, I'm confused about when or how they appear. Is it usually at random, or are there any criteria to be met in order to encounter them? If it is random, how often?

Comment: If it is random, you can't define _how often_.